# PyMongo dropping connections to mongos randomly

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, zato

I have a MongoDB cluster (2.6.3) with three mongos processes and two replica sets, with no sharding enabled.

In particular, I have 7 hosts (all are Ubuntu Server 14.04):

- host1: mongos + Client aplication
- host2: mongos + Client aplication
- host3: mongos + Client aplication
- host4: RS1_Primary (or RS1_Secondary) and RS2_Arbitrer
- host5: RS1_Secondary (or RS1_Primary)
- host6: RS2_Primary (or RS2_Secondary) and RS1_Arbitrer
- host7: RS2_Secondary (or RS2_Primary)

The Client application here is a [Zato Cluster](http://zato.io) with 4 gunicorn workers running in each server which accesses MongoDB using two `PyMongo.MongoClient` instances for each worker.
These `MongoClient` objects are created as follows:

```
MongoClient(mongo_hosts, read_preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED, w=0, max_pool_size=25)
MongoClient(mongo_hosts, read_preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED, w=0, max_pool_size=10)
```

where this mongo_hosts is: `'host1:27017,host2:27017,host2:27017'` in all servers.

So, in total, I have 12 `MongoClient` instances with `max_pool_size=25` (4 in each server) and 12 others with `max_pool_size=10` (also 4 in each server)

And my problem is:

When the Zato clusters are started and begin receiving requests (up to 10 rq/sec each, balanced using a simple round robin), a bunch of new connections are created and around 15-20 are then kept permanently open over the time in each mongos.

However, at some random point and with no apparent cause, a couple of connections are suddenly dropped at the same time in all three `mongos` and then the total number of connections keeps changing randomly until it stabilizes again after some minutes (from 5 to 10).
And while this happens, even though I see no slow queries in MongoDB logs (neither in mongos nor in mongod) the performance of the platform is severely reduced.

I have been isolating the problem and already tried to:

- change the connection string to `'localhost:27017`' in each MongoClient to see if the problem was in only one of the clients. The problem persisted, and it keeps affecting the three `mongos` at the same time, so it looks like something in the server side.
- add log traces to make sure that the performance is lost inside MongoClient. The result is that running a simple find query in MongoClient is clearly seen to last more than one second in the client side, while usually it's less than 10ms. However, as I said before, I see no slow queries at all in MongoDB logs (default profiling level: 100ms).
- monitor the platform activity to see if there's a load increase when this happens. There's none, and indeed it can even happen during low load periods.
- monitor other variables in the servers, such as cpu usage or disk activity. I found nothing suspicious at all.

So, the questions at the end are:

- Has anyone seen something similar (connections being dropped in PyMongo)?
- What else can I look at to debug the problem?
- Possible solution: `MongoClient` allows the definition of a `max_pool_size`, but I haven't found any reference to a `min_pool_size`. Is it possible to define so? Perhaps making the number of connections static would fix my performance problems.

Note about MongoDB version: I am currently running MongoDB 2.6.3 but I already had this problem before upgrading from 2.6.1, so it's nothing introduced in the last version.

Comment: There's no min_pool_size.

If a connection in one of the pools isn't used for a long time, it may be closed by an intervening load balancer or some network event. The next time PyMongo tries to use it, it finds the connection closed and opens a new connection to take its place. This is more likely after low-load periods.

Can you say why this is a problem? Is it very important that every connection last for a specific period of time?

Comment: I'm having similar problems and I'm using the Java Mongo driver with 3 MongoS instances.  I think the connections between the MongoS and the shard mongod instances are getting recycled and causing seconds of delays every minute.  I can't find any MongoS configs to adjust to see if it helps the problem.